# I am getting the crash on the FBAudienceNetwork.xcframework with the iOS version 15.6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-audience-network

Getting the crash on the FBAudienceNetwork.xcframework with the iOS version 15.6.1.

```
Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x2835e9d40> was mutated while being enumerated.0
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess
22
libobjc.A.dylib
class_getMethodImplementation
23
My App
+[FBAdLibAnalyzer _addClass:isClassMethod:]
24
My App
+[FBAdLibAnalyzer getMethodsTable:frameworks:]
25
My App
-[FBAdCrashHandler _generateMethodMapping:]
26
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
31
libsystem_pthread.dylib
start_wqthread
```

Comment: Seems to be an issue on their end. Maybe post an issue on their repo?